# crear migraciones de forma automatica de una base de datos existente en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

Como se pueden crear migraciones de una base de datos ya existente de forma automatica en laravel 5.4?
he encontrado este enlace

https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

pero me estan solicitando que no sea asi. Que no cree otros archivos para las llaves foraneas y otro para las tablas. Alguien sabe?

por ejemplo que cree las migraciones de este tipo

```
Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
 });
```

Ahi crea las relaciones y archivo de migracion de una base de datos ya existente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya pude resolver ese inconveniente.

en este link

https://github.com/beckenrode/mysql-workbench-export-laravel-5-migrations

es un plugin para crear las migraciones de forma automatica en laravel 5.4 apartir de una base de datos ya existente.
Ademas dejo un link de la explicacion del proceso

https://youtu.be/7ZFJpuHldWo

Espero haber ayudado en algo con eso.